# Go language and PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: json, go, postgresql-9.4

Is there a PostgreSQL library for Go Language that supports PostgreSQL version 9.4.
PostgreSQL 9.4 has support for JSON datatype and was wondering if it can be used with Go Language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [go `pq` library](https://github.com/lib/pq) should support PostgreSQL v9.4 and it has basic support for JSON types as strings (which seem to have been [added in v9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-json.html)).

```
// CREATE TABLE foo (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, stuff json);
// INSERT INTO foo (stuff) VALUES ('{"x":123}');

type Foo struct {
  Id    int,
  Stuff string,
}

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 1") // TODO: handle error
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
  foo := Foo{}
  err = rows.Scan(&foo.Id, &foo.Stuff) // TODO: handle error
  # main.Foo{Id:1, Stuff:"{\"x\":123}"}
}
```

You can either post-process the JSON string or create a custom type with a custom "Scan" method:

```
type Foo struct {
  Id    int,
  Stuff MyStuff,
}

func (e *MyStuff) Scan(value interface{}) error {
  // Value should be a []byte of the JSON string.
  // Do whatever you want with it here...
}
```

Comment: Please don't ignore errors in "example" code (it's almost by definition incorrect code). You know some fool will blindly cut-n-paste it and get into the habit of doing it that way and later make some other SO answerer's life difficult by asking a question filled with code ignoring the errors that would have told them what their problem was. </rant>

Comment: @DaveC: sure, that's legit, but I'm honestly torn on the subject.  I typically try to post as little code as possible to clearly demonstrate my intent (instead of drowning it in details) so things like error handling and cleanup are often omitted.  Is it my responsibility to make sure the cut-n-pasting fool doesn't blow his own foot off?

Comment: @DaveC: I've posted a meta question because I think you're point is valid http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290223/should-i-demonstrate-best-practices-in-example-code-or-opt-for-conciseness

Comment: Indeed, handling all possible cases in a simple answer can get distractingly verbose quite quickly. I wouldn't complain except that I see far too many SO questions that can't be answered without knowing the ignored errors; they're getting their examples from somewhere. Personally I at least put in a panic or a `// check error!!` comment; (it's even more hidden for things like `rows.Scan`).

Comment: Please note that the basic JSON data type was added in 9.2. Postgresql 9.4 adds the jsonb data type which supports a superset of operators.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring: cool, thanks for the info - I updated my answer to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [jmoiron/sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx). For any not common datatypes you can implement the `valuer` and `scanner` interfaces. I have done this for geography points with Postgis using this package.